# In query taking too long

Tags: mysql

I have a query with IN clause, It's taking too long to process, don't know what is going wrong:

```
 Select * from orders
 where orders.id IN 
(
    SELECT orders.id FROM `orders` 
    INNER JOIN `line_items` ON `line_items`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
    WHERE (line_items.coupon_id = 133) 
    GROUP BY orders.id 
    UNION 
    SELECT orders.id FROM `orders` 
    INNER JOIN `payments` ON `payments`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
    WHERE (payments.coupon_id = 133) 
    GROUP BY orders.id 
    UNION 
    SELECT orders.id FROM `orders` 
    INNER JOIN `coupon_applications` ON `coupon_applications`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
    WHERE (coupon_applications.coupon_id =133) 
    GROUP BY orders.id
);
```

However the following part is working fine:

```
SELECT orders.id FROM `orders` 
INNER JOIN `line_items` ON `line_items`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
WHERE (line_items.coupon_id = 133) 
GROUP BY orders.id 
UNION 
SELECT orders.id FROM `orders` 
INNER JOIN `payments` ON `payments`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
WHERE (payments.coupon_id = 133) 
GROUP BY orders.id 
UNION 
SELECT orders.id FROM `orders` 
INNER JOIN `coupon_applications` ON `coupon_applications`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
WHERE (coupon_applications.coupon_id =133) 
GROUP BY orders.id
```

Comment: how many records did the inner query return? And do you really need to do `select *`?

Comment: It returns just 98 records.

Comment: is `id` the primary key in `orders` table? How many records and columns does the `order` table have?

Comment: yes id is primary key. Order table have thousands of records and around 50 columns.

Comment: you need to provide more information when you try to optimize a query.
table descriptions, index information, type of operations on table...

Comment: 50 columns? do you really need to do select * ?. Are you running this query when simultaneous updates are happening? If yes you can try setting the `isolation level` to `uncommited read`

Comment: yeah, I don't think there should be any problem to fetch just 98 records via IN clause. I tried fetching records in two steps first to get ids and second fetch all the orders via IN clause with ids then everything worked fine.

Comment: You may have valid reasons for constructing a table with 50 columns, but it can be indicative of poor design. Also, if proper DDLs were provided, I suspect this query could be greatly optimized

Comment: I can't help it, It was already written. For making it change it will take all the efforts also my client wouldn't like it to change at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it run successfully after removing 'GROUP BY orders.id' from my nested query. However couldn't find the reason why it was not working for Group By in nested query.

Hopefully this would help others.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How much time is it taking ?

There are lot of constraints to optimize query execution. It seems there is no problem with your query except "SELECT * ", that you better change (but this will not affect drastically your query performance).

Still if you think query is not proper just provide more details regarding this questions.

Comment: Have you ever seen any living example where SELECT * was significantly (I mean, not just 210ms instead of 190ms) slower in MySQL than select of the columns? If you claim that in stackoverflow, many people will read and believe you. I have seen examples, where WHERE ... IN (select...) was completely broken.

Comment: Hi @flaschenpost. 100% agreed. Edited my answer. Plz check.

Answer (score 0):

First: Avoid the subselect with IN(), it seems to break the optimizer (EDIT: for example, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63671/24475). Just do

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM orders as o
inner join...
UNION
SELECT o.*
FROM orders as o
UNION
...
```

When you have many rows in some table for one order, WHERE EXISTS could help (or not help, it depends):

```
 SELECT o.* 
 FROM orders o
 WHERE EXISTS 
 (
     select id from lineitem li where li.coupon_id = 133 and li.order_id = o.id)
 )
 OR EXISTS
 (
     select id from payments where...
 )
```